# installation laravel in nginx.conf error in virtual host

Tags: laravel, nginx

I try to install Laravel in Ubuntu 18.04 with Nginx in Amazon AWS.

I follow this nice tutorial:
https://linux4one.com/how-to-install-laravel-php-framework-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04/

but in the last instruction:

ngnix -t

I get this error:

> nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/laravel" failed (2: No
>   such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:62 nginx:
>   configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

And when I go to this file in line 62, I see this:

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

```
    user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

here my file /etc/nginx/sites-available/laravel.conf

```
server {
         listen 80;
         listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

         # Log files for Debugging
         access_log /var/log/nginx/laravel-access.log;
         error_log /var/log/nginx/laravel-error.log;

         # Webroot Directory for Laravel project
         root /var/www/laravel/public;
         index index.php index.html index.htm;

         # Your Domain Name
         server_name 99.80.169.66;

         location / {
                 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
         }

         # PHP-FPM Configuration Nginx
         location ~ \.php$ {
                 try_files $uri =404;
                 fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                 fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                 fastcgi_index index.php;
                 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                 include fastcgi_params;
         }
 }
```

here is my file /var/www/laravel/.env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=laravel
DB_PASSWORD=66345345

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: here is my file:

Answer (score 1):

try this
1. install nginx

```
`apt-get install nginx`
```

2. install php 7.3

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install php7.3

    sudo apt install php7.3-cli php7.3-fpm php7.3-json php7.3-pdo php7.3-mysql php7.3-zip php7.3-gd  php7.3-mbstring php7.3-curl php7.3-xml php7.3-bcmath php7.3-json
```

3.install mysql server

```
    sudo apt install mysql-server
    sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

enter password and y to all

```
    sudo mysql
    ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'very_strong_password'

    ;
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'administrator'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'very_strong_password';
```

4. setup for remote sql server

   `nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

   bind-address = 127.0.0.1
   to:
   bind-address = 0.0.0.0

   `systemctl restart mysql.service`

```
    sudo mysql
    CREATE USER 'sid'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'strong_password';

    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'sid'@'localhost'
    ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;

    CREATE USER 'sid'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'strong_password';

    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'sid'@'%'
        ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

5. install composer

`apt-get install composer`

6. install redis server

`apt install redis-server`

`nano /etc/redis/redis.conf`

change text
`

```
supervised no
to 
supervised systemd
```

restart redis

```
systemctl restart redis.service
```

testing redis
redis-cli
ping
reply pong

change redis password

nano /etc/redis/redis.conf
uncomment # requirepass foobared

full details here
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-redis-on-ubuntu-18-04

7. install nodejs server

   ## Using Ubuntu

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

## Using Debian, as root

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs

8.upload site
9.grant permission
 sudo chown -R www-data:www-data storage/
 sudo chown -R www-data:www-data public/

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /home/sid/website/searustasia/public;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /home/sid/website/searustasia/ssl/searustasia.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/sid/website/searustasia/ssl/searustasia.key;
    server_name  api.searustasia.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
       fastcgi_pass             unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

}
```

don't forget to restart nginx

Comment: Hi sid heart, for help me, but I follow your instructions and I get many errors.
Please with this instructions:
https://linux4one.com/how-to-install-laravel-php-framework-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04/
all work fine for me, except the last step, sure is a small detail to do.
Please can check what`s can be wrong?

Comment: I added in my comment the code of 2 files:
/etc/nginx/sites-available/laravel.conf
/var/www/laravel/.env

Comment: @fireDevelop.com i can't see file you added to comment

Comment: @fireDevelop.com [contact me](https://www.facebook.com/imsidzz) if you still getting problem